# Telegram-бот. Python, через telebot. Работа с кнопками

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, button

Нет реакции при нажатии кнопок в "consent_message", то есть не выводится сообщение из "answer_no". При этом, если "answer_no" поставить после "start_message" и в call.data заменить переменную на 'hi', то "answer_no" работает.

То есть как-то нарушена связь между второй и третьей частью. Или как-то некорректно завершается вторая часть.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    hi = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    hi.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Привет', callback_data='hi'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствуем, {0.first_name}!   '.format(message.from_user),reply_markup=hi)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def consent_message(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'hi':
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
            consent = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)      
            consent.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Согласен',
              callback_data='yes'))
            consent.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет. Я хочу 
              покинуть данный бот',callback_data='no'))
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Далее будут отправлены вопросы анкетирования.', reply_markup=consent)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer_no(call):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'no':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жаль, что Вы не останетесь с нами. Следуйте ниже написанной инструкции, чтобы покинуть бот.')
```

Comment: разместите все `if call.data` под одним `@bot.callback_query_handler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно помочь

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def consent_message(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'hi':
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
            consent = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)      
            consent.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Согласен',
              callback_data='yes'))
            consent.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет. Я хочу 
              покинуть данный бот',callback_data='no'))
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Далее будут отправлены вопросы анкетирования.', reply_markup=consent)
        elif call.data == 'no':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жаль, что Вы не останетесь с нами. Следуйте ниже написанной инструкции, чтобы покинуть бот.')
```

Comment: `elif call.data == 'no':`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]