# Python Telebot Проблема с inline keyboard

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, inline

Проблема в том что, я создал игру и у игры есть свои кнопки в вниз наверх лево вправо, она работает все нормально, но я решил создать еще вопросы ответы с inline keyboard, и тут когда я нажимаю на какую то из кнопок под сообщением вылазит ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 121, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
ges\telebot\__init__.py", line 660, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, a
llowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
ges\telebot\__init__.py", line 722, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
ges\telebot\__init__.py", line 682, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
ges\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
ges\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "error.py", line 66, in callback_func
    user_data = maps[query.from_user.id]
KeyError: 1309129529
```

Код:

```py
import config
import time
import traceback
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import telebot
import random
from telebot import types

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

from mg import get_map_cell

# bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

cols, rows = 8, 8  # Переменные из игры
# Клавиатура для игры
keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.row(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('←', callback_data='left'),
             telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('↑', callback_data='up'),
             telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('↓', callback_data='down'),
             telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('→', callback_data='right'))

maps = {}


# функция для игры
def get_map_str(map_cell, player):
    map_str = ""
    for y in range(rows * 2 - 1):
        for x in range(cols * 2 - 1):
            if map_cell[x + y * (cols * 2 - 1)]:
                map_str += "⬛"
            elif (x, y) == player:
                map_str += ""
            else:
                map_str += "⬜"
        map_str += "\n"

    return map_str


# Command /play
@bot.message_handler(commands=['play'])
def play_message(message):
    map_cell = get_map_cell(cols, rows)

    user_data = {
        'map': map_cell,
        'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
    }

    maps[message.from_user.id] = user_data
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "To win you need to reach the opposite corner")
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, get_map_str(map_cell, (0, 0)), reply_markup=keyboard)


# Функция для игры
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_func(query):
    user_data = maps[query.from_user.id]
    new_x, new_y = user_data['x'], user_data['y']

    if query.data == 'left':
        new_x -= 1
    if query.data == 'right':
        new_x += 1
    if query.data == 'up':
        new_y -= 1
    if query.data == 'down':
        new_y += 1

    if new_x < 0 or new_x > 2 * cols - 2 or new_y < 0 or new_y > rows * 2 - 2:
        return None
    if user_data['map'][new_x + new_y * (cols * 2 - 1)]:
        return None

    user_data['x'], user_data['y'] = new_x, new_y

    if new_x == cols * 2 - 2 and new_y == rows * 2 - 2:
        you_won = random.choice(["You won", "'Well done' won such an easy game"])
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat.id,
                              message_id=query.message.id,
                              text=you_won)
        return None

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat.id,
                          message_id=query.message.id,
                          text=get_map_str(user_data['map'], (new_x, new_y)),
                          reply_markup=keyboard)


# Condition with text
@bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
def get_token(message):
    if "teslabot" in message.text.lower():
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("How are you)", callback_data="How are you)")
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Who are you??", callback_data="Who are you??")
        markup.add(item1, item2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Did you call me?", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == "How are you)":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Yes, ok, sort of")
            elif call.data == "Who are you??":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "I do not know who I am:(")

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1354665/234134

Comment: Violet Спасибо большое